# PHP files not detected using the $_FILES array

Tags: php, html, forms

### The problem

The $_FILES['file'] array is set, yet it's empty whenever I try to use it.

### What I tried

- Googling
- Setting file upload to On in php.ini (both Xampp and project file root)
- Uploading one file at a time (just a wild try at fixing the problem
- Debugging the entire code for a month trying to solve this problem

### What I know for a fact

- The path to the onSubmit is correct
- The name of the input in the form and the name after $_FILES['file'] is exactly the same
- The form has all it's required attributes
- The input has type="file" and multiple in it

### My code for the form(HTML) and the file engine(PHP)

```
<html>
<form method="POST" action="../php/post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Title</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="case" value=1>
<input type="title" name="pname">
<h3>Message</h3>
<input type="message" name="pmsg">
<h3>Images</h3>
<input type="file" name="pimg[]" multiple>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</html>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['pimg'])){
$noFiles = 1;
echo "Files found...\n";
} else {
$noFiles = 0;
echo "Files not found...\n";
echo (!empty($_FILES['file']['pimg']));
echo $_FILES['file']['pimg'][0];
}
?>
```

### Output

The If determines the array is empty, the last echo causes an error

Comment: what is `$_FILES['file']['pimg']`? Isn't it `$_FILES['pimg']`?

Comment: Try to be *specific* in your description of what happens. You say "the last echo causes an error", but don't show us what the error says. Even if you don't know what it means, showing it to us will allow us to explain it to you. You could also add the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` which will probably reveal the problem.

Comment: And all this can be solved with __one line of code__: `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: I have tried print_r(); it returns nothing. The error just says that ['pimg'] doesnt exist

Comment: _"I have tried print_r(); it returns nothing."_ `print_r($_FILES);` will always show something.

Comment: This makes no sense. Put `var_dump($_FILES);` as the first line in post.php and paste the exact, full response here. Also please stop abbreviating or paraphrasing the error message, its really not helpful. It's like telling the doctor only half your symptoms! Paste the exact, full error message and tell us which line caused it

Comment: Also, your code never checks for potential errors in the upload...Read about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: To check not empty use $_FILES['pimg']['name'] use like this

Comment: _The error just says that ['pimg'] doesnt exist_ that's your clue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not far off.
$_FILES['file']['pimg'] should be $_FILES['pimg']
You should also check to see if there is something selected. $_FILES['pimg']['size'] checks the filesize. If 0, nothing is selected

This way works.

```
<?php

    if ($_FILES['pimg']['size'] != 0){
        $noFiles = 1;
        echo "Files found...\n";
        echo $_FILES['pimg']['name'][0];
    } else {
        $noFiles = 0;
        echo "Files not found...\n";
    
    /* This will always be empty placed here as no files have been found */
    //echo (!empty($_FILES['file']['pimg']));
    //echo $_FILES['file']['pimg']['name'][0];
    }

?>
```

Comment: This won't work, when the form has a file field named pimg, `$_FILES['pimg']` won't be empty, even if nothing is uploaded.

Comment: You are correct @shingo Edited the code above

Comment: Shingo is incorrect, that fixed the issue :D